# Not able to install pod in mac os

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

i am not able to install any project POD except from alamofire

Mac config :
MacBook Pro M1 Chip 2020 13.3-inch (2560 × 1600)
masOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Space 81.36 GB available of 245.11 GB

Cocoa POD Version : 1.15.5

when i try to install pod error like below

Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `TestsApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

my pod file is

```
target 'AppTest' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'UITableView+FDTemplateLayoutCell'
pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C'
pod 'CRToast', '~> 0.0.7'
pod 'GLCalendarView', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'SDWebImage
end
target 'AppTests' do
end
```

that same pod work on other mac very well.

Comment: "Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile". Could you share your podfile?

Comment: thanks @Larme for respond 
i update information in question.

Answer (score 0):

near the top of your Podfile, try adding in:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

or whatever minimum iOS version you're hoping to support in your code.

[The "What Is A Podfile?" documentation at Cocoapods.org](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) offers some good detail and explanations.